Laravel 11 SFTP disk not listing directories or files, while Laravel 10 works fine
I'm facing an issue with SFTP disk configuration in Laravel 11. While the connection is established successfully, I'm unable to list directories or files from the SFTP server. Interestingly, the same configuration works perfectly in Laravel 10.
Environment:

Fresh Laravel 11 project
Windows Server 2021 VM (SFTP server)
Added packages:

"league/flysystem-sftp-v3": "^3.0"
"league/flysystem-path-prefixing": "^3.0"



Configuration:
In config/filesystem.php, I've added two new disks:
'sftp' => [
    'driver' => 'sftp',
    'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
    'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
    'privateKey' => env('SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY'),
    'passphrase' => env('SFTP_PASSPHRASE'),
    'visibility' => 'private',
    'directory_visibility' => 'private',
],
'export' => [
    'driver' => 'scoped',
    'disk' => 'sftp',
    'prefix' => env('EXPORT_PREFIX', 'E:/serverfolders'),
]

My .env file contains:
SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY="/location/of/key/file"
SFTP_HOST="fs01.myserver.local"
SFTP_USERNAME="user1@myserver.local"
SFTP_PASSPHRASE="PassPhrase0fKeyFile"

Problem:
When I try to list directories or files using Laravel's Storage facade, I get empty results:
Storage::disk('sftp')->directories()
// Returns: ["C:", "E:"]

Storage::disk('sftp')->directories('E:/')
// Returns: []

Storage::disk('sftp')->allFiles('E:/')
// Returns: []

Storage::disk('sftp')->directories('E:/serverfolders')
// Returns: []

Storage::disk('sftp')->allFiles('E:/serverfolders')
// Returns: []

However, I can successfully connect to the server using WinSCP with the same configuration.
What I've Tried:

Verified the SFTP connection is established
Confirmed the same configuration works in Laravel 10
Double-checked file permissions on the SFTP server

Question:
What could be causing this issue in Laravel 11, and how can I resolve it to successfully list directories and files from the SFTP server?
